# How to pass list of arguments in criteria query , jpa?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I am new in JPA but have to implement my project in that technology

what I'm trying to do is build via `CriteriaQuery` some db query, but have no idea how to pass list Of parameters to the code below :

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyClass> c = qb
            .createQuery(MyClass.class);
    Root<MyClassPK> p = c
            .from(MyClass.class);

    c.where(qb.equal(qb.trim((p.<MyClass> get("id")).<String> get("Name")),
    HERE LIST OF ARGS HOW TO PASS ?? ));    
TypedQuery<MyClass> q = em.createQuery(c);
```

the code looks pretty complex cause of complex database architecutre. Could somebody tell me how to resolve my problem ? Or maybe only one solution is for (...) ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well your question, you need an "in" condition:

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyClass> c = qb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
Root<MyClassPK> p = c.from(MyClass.class);

// c.where(qb.equal(qb.trim((p.<MyClass> get("id")).<String> get("Name")), HERE LIST OF ARGS HOW TO PASS ?? ));    

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("name1");
names.add("name2");
names.add("name3");
c.where(qb.trim((p.<MyClass> get("id")).<String> get("Name")).in(names));

TypedQuery<MyClass> q = em.createQuery(c);
```

Comment: thanks for answer ! I will try in job after weekend , greetings

Comment: unfortunately , your tip doesn't work. My eclipse underline trim method and says: "Please rename in file" ... Thanks

Comment: thanks for being care my friend , but the result is still not what I've expected. I mean I need to equal that trim to the list of args , so it's like qb.equal( qb.trim(...) , and here list of args )  your idea doesn't working in my case :(